# Improve AngularJS performance on multiple levels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, model-view-controller, localization

I'm writing a **complex, multi-component app using AngularJS**. Currently, the main components are ready and ***I want to improve the performance of the app***.

**After a short investigation on the field, I found some very useful resources:**

[11 Tips to Improve AngularJS Performance](http://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance/)

[Improving AngularJS wep app performance example](http://bahmutov.calepin.co/improving-angular-web-app-performance-example.html)

[AngularJS Performance in large applications](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-performance-large-applications)

**Anyway, I need some additional advises on a few topics:**

**1. Script and Services/Factories loading**

- currently, all scripts are **loaded at the bottom of the** `<body></body>` tag inside `index.html`. Therefore, when the user loads directly a `ui-route` or we simply reload given page, all the scripts are loaded again. **I want to load the scripts only in states that use the given script.**
- **Services/Factories/etc. are loaded the same way**. This causes pages which do NOT need the given e.g. Service to load it and this is slowing the performance, because of the big data load. **I need to initialize/load them only when they are needed in the current state.**

**2. Translation/Localization**

- I'm using Angular Translate - i18n [Reference](https://angular-translate.github.io/), but when I'm translating the page elements I must use e.g. `<button>{{btnName | translate}}</button`. This technique and the overall usage of filters is pointed as one of the biggest performance drawbacks. The page has a lot of elements so this really might slow the loading. **Is there any better solution or any workaround?**

**3. Overall**

- I've read the multiple threads on `ng-repeat` and its `track by` feature, **so I assume it done**, but I'm still **not 100% sure** that I **understand** the `$digest` (`$apply`) cycles correctly.
- **I read some comments that we should "avoid bind anything directly to a function", but I don't quite get it**.

**Any additional comments or advises relative to AngularJS and its performance are welcome!**

> Thank you :)

Comment: 1. you can lazy load those with `$ocLazyload`. 2. no good angular way to solve I know (although I personally kind of solve it by using my own renderer). 3. `track by` is good when you have a lot of items on `ng-repeat`. binding to function is expensive because they run a lot proportional to `$$watchers` count.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will look this $ocLazyload. I'm currently having troubles with Grunt and Gulp because the project is quite big and it's very hard to integrate them at this point :(

Answer (score 2):

Reading the above, it looks like you already tried to optimize AngularJS itself. However, there is no mention of optimizations on your build process. I guess it would be wise for you to investigate Grunt or Gulp. With these tools you can concatenate and minify all your JavaScript to a single minified file. This way you only have a one-time payload while initialising your site.

Check this https://medium.com/@dickeyxxx/best-practices-for-building-angular-js-apps-266c1a4a6917

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I will check it out, but still I'm facing the script/angular loading issues and the filters which I believe is the most performance consuming :)

Comment: If you concatenate all JS into one file, all the script/loading issues should improve significant. How do you measure performance currently?

Comment: I'm using Batarang and Chrome's Timeline. I might do this Grunt story right away and see if it "boosts" the app :)